# How to add more than one svg images in a stack on a screen?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to add more than one SVG image on screen, I am getting a white box instead of that image are some portion of it is getting cropped out.

```
Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Positioned(
            top: 104,
            left: 85,
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/path.svg',
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: 104,
            left: 85,
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/path.svg',
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Image.asset('assets/family.png'),
          ),
])
```

I want to get each SVG drawn on the screen on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Insert images within a `Row`

example

[image]

like this

```
Stack(children: [

  Row(children: <Widget>[
    SvgPicture.asset(
      'assets/path.svg',
    ),
   SvgPicture.asset(
      'assets/path.svg',
    ),
  ],),
```